# CAS [v5.3.6] / Problem with setting the appropriate language

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat, cas

I currently working with cas v5.3.6, after migration from v5.0.4 i have a problem, with setting te proper language.

Setting the language in cookie and read by CookieLocaleResolver works very well, only one view doesn't work as expected / oauthConfirmView.

- system locale is set as PL,
- cas default locale property set as PL,
- webapp set as tomcat,
- spring: 4.3.20.RELEASE
- spring-boot: 1.5.14.RELEASE
- pacj4: 3.1.0

Authorization: https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html#responsegrant-types

## Redirect flow:

#### 1. Provide Credentials

```
Request GET: https://domain/cas/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ClientId&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url
- Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Response: (302)
- Location: https://domain/cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?client_id=ClientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url&client_name=CasOAuthClient
```

#### 2. Generate Ticket

```
Request GET: https://domain/cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?client_id=ClientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url&client_name=CasOAuthClient
- Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Response: (302)
- Location: https://domain/cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?client_id=ClientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url&client_name=CasOAuthClient&ticket=ST-TICKET-GENERATED
```

#### 3. Validate Ticket

```
Request GET: https://domain/cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?client_id=ClientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url&client_name=CasOAuthClient&ticket=ST-TICKET-GENERATED
- Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Response: (302)
- Content-Language: pl
- Location: https://domain/cas/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ClientId&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url
```

#### 4. Share profile / oauthConfirmView

```
Request GET: https://domain/cas/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ClientId&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url
- Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Response: (200)
- Content-Language: en-US
```

After this flow i got view in english language, does anyone know why this is happening?

Thx for any advices ;)